# Black screen on boot after adding something to xorg.conf folder

Tags: boot, display

Black screen after boot after changing adding something to conf folder.

I added a `xorg.conf.d` file called "50-gamma.conf" which contains:

```
display-setup-script=xrandr --output eDP1 -- gamma 1:0.93:1
```

Then I restarted my computer and it boots to a black screen. What happened?

I followed the instruction of the second answer from:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/633455/xrandr-not-saving-settings-permanetly-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I can confirm this

Comment: delete the `.conf` which you have created, it will solve

Comment: are you able to delete the `.conf` file?

Comment: Nope, I had to reinstall. I don't have access to terminal at black screen.

Comment: wait I will provide answer :) try my answer and let me know

Comment: I have already reinstalled, so I don't have to do it anymore. But thanks though, I can use this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to provide you a solution to get back from black screen. The black screen is caused by the `.conf` file that you have created. First remove it, it will solve the issue.

*Note* : *I have tested this solution*

Step-1: Restart system. Go to  advanced options --> select recovery mode.

step-2: 
  Now using the arrow keys scroll down to **root** and then hit  <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image: Imgur]

Step-3: Run the following commands to remove:

```
mount -rw -o remount /
rm -rf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-gamma.conf 
reboot
```

Explanation: The first command changes permission, second remove file you have created.

As a side note: [If I follow instruction from blog/web, is that always safe?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649217/if-i-follow-instruction-from-blog-web-is-that-always-safe/649244#649244)